# Wi-fi keeps turning off

Tags: wi-fi, settings

Within the last few days, my Wi-fi setting keeps switching to "off".

It does this even when the screen is on and I'm actively using the device.

I've checked the couple apps I still have that help with conserving battery and none of them seem to affect wi-fi. In any event I haven't installed any recently nor updated any settings in them.

What should I be checking? How can I fix this?

Motorola Droid, Android 2.2.1, unrooted

Comment: Have you tried more than one WAP or is this all happening on one?

Comment: You would probably know this, but have you checked to see if you have any rogue Tasker profiles configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well color me dumb.

I'd recently installed an app called "Autopilot". It's supposed to put the device in Airplane mode when there's no cellular signal. I work in the middle of an office building so it happens a lot. It burns through battery while it tries to establish a signal.

The settings led me to believe that it wouldn't touch wi-fi unless I turned a specific setting on. I didn't, because I didn't want to mess with that.

However, after I uninstalled the app, the behavior has stopped.

I should have checked that first.

Let that be a lesson: Just because you don't think it's that new app you installed giving you grief, it just might be after all.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen to me once.  I think it had something to do with WiFi being turned on while flight mode was on, but I don't know why.  I fixed it by:

1. Turning off WiFi
2. Turning on flight mode
3. Rebooting
4. Turning off flight mode
5. Rebooting
6. Turning on WiFi